# How to deal with type "Time*" (set in the Extension Builder) in Controller and View of Extbase extension

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I created the entity `Appointment` in my extension builder.
Each `Appointment` is happening on a certain day and has a start time and an end time.
It never goes beyond a day so I only need one date.
That's why I added those 3 properties to my model in the extension builder:
[image]

When creating a new appointment in the frontend I now know how to deal with the date format but no idea how to convert the time to the fitting Integer as the extension builder set it in my model.
[image]
When trying to create a new appointment I get this error:

> An error occurred while trying to call
>   vendor\extname\Controller\AppointmentController->createAction()
>
> ```
> newAppointment.startTime:
>     "09:35" is no integer.
>     The given subject was NULL.
> newAppointment.endTime:
>     "10:35" is no integer.
> ```

In my controller I have this function which works for the Date:

```
public function initializeAction() {
        if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('newAppointment')) {
            $this->arguments->getArgument('newAppointment')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()->forProperty('startDate')->setTypeConverterOption('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Property\\TypeConverter\\DateTimeConverter',\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\DateTimeConverter::CONFIGURATION_DATE_FORMAT,'d.m.Y');
        }
    }
```

I tried adding:

```
$this->arguments->getArgument('newAppointment')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()->forProperty('startTime')->setTypeConverterOption('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Property\\TypeConverter\\IntegerConverter',\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\IntegerConverter);
```

but that was a fail as it says:

> Fatal error: Undefined constant
>   'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\IntegerConverter' in ...AppointmentController...

I even checked that path and the IntegerConverter is there...
Not sure if I'm supposed to use it in this case or if there's some other simple way to do this...?

And also once this works, how would I display it - currently for the date I'm doing:

```
{appointment.startDate->f:format.date(format:'d.m.Y')}
```

but will I be able to do this with my Time Integer?:

```
{appointment.startTime->f:format.date(format:'H:i')}
```

Comment: What happens if you change the type for `startTime` in your model to `DateTime` or `\DateTime`? Be sure to clear the caches from the install tool after the change.

Comment: if I change them to \DateTime in the model and convert them in my controller with the Format "H:i" it doesn't give an error and seems to work...  
But I don't see the point of type "Time*" then, if I'd do it like that because I could just change the type to "DateTime" and the Extension Builder would change my model automatically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `setTypeConverterOption` doesn't expect a class, but a constant from this class. Since the `IntegerConverter` has no options, this is meaningless anyway. But this clears up one of the errors.

You can use time fields (internally handled as integer, eval `time` in TCA), but there's some manual work needed.

At first you need a converter that determines the timestamp from a given time. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/visol/easyvote/blob/master/Classes/Property/TypeConverter/TimestampConverter.php).

Then, in your `initializeCreateAction` and `initializeUpdateAction` use the converter to convert the given DateTime from the frontend to the integer to be saved in the DB:

```
$propertyMappingConfiguration->forProperty('fromTime')->setTypeConverter($this->objectManager->get('My\\Extension\\Property\\TypeConverter\\TimestampConverter'))->setTypeConverterOption('My\\Extension\\Property\\TypeConverter\\TimestampConverter', \My\\Extension\Property\TypeConverter\TimestampConverter::CONFIGURATION_DATE_FORMAT, 'H:i');
```

Then you should be fine saving the time to the integer field.

Comment: I get this error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object in /ext/myExt/Classes/Property/TypeConverter/TimestampConverter.php on line 38 `
But you said "the given DateTime"...I feel like that's the problem, I think I'm just getting a string, but I don't know how to prove it or to change it to a DateTime. I'm using this field in the front end now: `<f:form.textfield property="startTime" type="date" value="{appointment.starttime -> f:format.date(format:'H:i')}" class="app-timepicker" />`

Comment: Or is it because I didn't define `objectManager`anywhere?

Comment: Your error means that there is no `DateTime` object. Please debug `$source` and `$dateFormat` in the `TimestampConverter` to find out what's missing.

Comment: Like I suspected, it is a string - `string(5) "08:00" NULL` what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using a Boostrap DateTime picker (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and `%R` as format, see example here: https://github.com/visol/ext-easyvote_education/blob/master/Resources/Private/Partials/Panel/FormFields.html#L39.

Comment: I looked at that example a bit before and I was very confused about how the object's values can be loaded without "name"+"value" or a "property"??  It's only using "id". Ok, so it might have something to do with my timepicker? I will look into it.

Comment: it finally works - the problem was that I didn't take a detailed look into the converter class before where I should've changed the name of the extension folder. And my extension builder somehow didn't create getters and setters for me when I changed the types of my properties back to `Time*`.

Comment: I just noticed that I get an error if I type in a wrong time value...I thought extbase would handle this automatically but it doesn't, so how should I validate this the best way?